# PowerShell, How to check for an installed Chocolatey package

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

For a while I was using a construct like this to check if a package was already installed before running the installer:

```
if (!(Test-Path "Program Files\7-Zip")) { 
    $command = "if ((choco list --local-only 7zip) -match '^0 packages') { choco install 7zip -y }"
    Start-Process "powershell.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -ArgumentList "-sta -noprofile -executionpolicy unrestricted $command"
}
```

That worked well for a few years, but it now looks like they have changed the switches in `Chocolatey` so that `choco list --local-only 7zip` now generates an error:

```
Invalid argument --local-only. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.
```

What would be the most efficient way to test whether a `Chocolatey` package is installed or not now?

Comment: If this code is being run _inside_ a package (i.e. as part of the `chocolateyInstall.ps1` for example, then it's not recommended. Much like typing `google` into Google, running the `choco` command inside a package is not recommended.

Comment: Good to know. I would really like to create chocolatey packages, but I never really found out how, so this is just for my scripts that configure systems and make use of the freely available packages. As @Gary Ewan Park points out  `choco list 7zip` looks ideal for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, with the release of Chocolatey CLI 2.0.0 (https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/release-notes#may-31-2023) the function of the `choco list` command changed. So now, instead of doing:

`choco list --local-only 7zip`

you can simply do:

`choco list 7zip`

The `list` command now *only* acts on local packages, so the `--local-only` option is not required.